f:ajax listener method with own class/object as parameter
The signature of f:ajax listener is void listener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event). I've the following working code:
Facelet:
...
<f:ajax listener="#{myBean.myListener(myObject)}" />
...

Bean:
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
  // ...
  public void myListener(final MyClass myObject /* <-- Is that legal? */) {
    // do something with myObject
  }
}

Is the usage of my own class/object as parameter in myListener legal? The code is working. If not why not?
JSF: Mojarra 2.3.14
